# External hard drive with multiple pieces of unallocated space. How do I join them together?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I just got a 3TB external drive. When I first plugged it in, it showed up as a 2.7TB drive (as expected). Whenever I get a new external device I like to format it (and admittedly, I succeeded initially with the simple right click format from My Computer) but I wanted to try something different. So I went into Computer Management and deleted the partition on the hard drive and the following came up:

[image: Computer Management 1]

So that's strange. What started as a single partition now became two blocks of unallocated space. I can only partitions in the first block:

[image: Computer Management 2]

I am also not able to extend the first partition. I created the partition as large as Windows would allow me.

**How can I join these two unallocated spaces back together again?**

I am using Windows 7 Professional, if that means anything special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is format the drive as a GPT partition. What is happening is that you are being limited by the specifications of MBR. MBR < 2tb. Once you change the partitioning  of the device you will be able to have one large drive. Get there by right clicking on the Disk 2 and change it from there. That way you don't need any third-party software.

Comment: Already used GParted but this will be good to know in the future. Thanks. I've changed the accepted answer (sorry, Doc, this guy needs some more reputation anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Can you not click on where it says "Disk 2" and do some kind of reinitialization there?

If not, a quickish solution I'd use is just burn [GParted to a CD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.9.0-7/gparted-live-0.9.0-7.iso/download) and use it to fix up your partitioning accordingly.

Comment: No relevant options are available in that context menu. I'm thinking I did something that Windows can't see for some reason and therefore I will have to go with GParted.

Comment: KPthunder: If I knew a quick Windowsy solution, that'd probably end up being faster. But I never really learn such solutions for stuff like this cause I always end up finding a fast linuxy solution. GParted is AWESOME.

Comment: Yes, I like GParted as well. I just don't like shutting off my computer to use it. I'm about to go ahead and use GParted. If it's able to fix the disk I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It'll work, it's GParted!?!! Indeed rebooting is lame, but that's what you get for running Windows ;)

Comment: Well, it took a while (freaking graphics settings, man...) but it worked. I wonder what happened in the first place... When I started up Windows again it said that one of my USB devices had malfunctioned and wasn't recognized... but the drive appears to be working fine...

Comment: That's trippy dude. Maybe go look up maintenance utils by your drive's manufacturer and see if you can run some diagnostics to make sure everything's working okay... Or maybe your external enclosure is screwy?

Answer (score 0):

Go to disk management create a new volume and assign a drive letter to the new volume. If it doesn't show a drive letter right away, just assign it again but don't delete the volume you just created. Next go into diskpart in cmd > list disk > select disk (whatever number it is) > create primary partition. Ba da bing, ba da boom.

You can also find the instructions here:
https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/format-usb-flash-drives-showing-the-wrong-capacity-the-easy-way/ It's under this section of the page ---> Fix An Incorrect Size USB Drive Using Command Prompt